# linq2db. fallback for provider specific function

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, linq2db

I'm using Linq-to-DB (linq2db, linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore).

My software supports several database providers (SQL Server, PostgreSQL). There is a case when I need to use a provider specific function for SQL Server, and for PostgreSQL use an alternative option, or ignore it.

For example, I need this code to work with two providers.

In the case of SQL Server, the `ISJSON` must be performed, and in the case of PostgreSQL, it must be ignored:

```cs
var d1 = db.Invoice
           .Where(i => SqlFn.IsJson(i.InvoiceState) == true)
           .ToLinqToDB().ToList();
```

Now in the case of PostgreSQL I get an error

> 'IsJson(i.InvoiceState)' cannot be converted to SQL

How to do this correctly?

Comment: there are some example of custom sql per provider here https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/tree/master/Source/LinqToDB/Sql/

Comment: @siggemannen SqlFn.IsJson - is but a built-in function in linq2db. I don't need to make a new one.

Comment: Show your `SqlFn.IsJson` function definition.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it is not my function. https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/master/Source/LinqToDB/DataProvider/SqlServer/SqlFn.cs#L1638

Comment: Well. in this case we need another function. What to do if database do not support IsJson? return false?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv in my case the best solution is to be able to simply ignore this condition in sql. Something like database specific hints (https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Query-Extensions.html#database-specific-hint-extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create other function which handles other providers:

```cs
public static class DbFunctions
{
    [ExpressionMethod(ProviderName.SqlServer, nameof(SqlServerIsJson))]
    [ExpressionMethod(nameof(EmptyIsJson))]
    [return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(expression))]
    public static bool? IsJson(string? expression)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"'{nameof(IsJson)}' is a server side only function.");
    }
    
    static Expression<Func<string?, bool?>> SqlServerIsJson()
        => e => SqlFn.IsJson(e);

    static Expression<Func<string?, bool?>> EmptyIsJson()
        => e => false;
}
```

And use in your queries:

```cs
var d1 = db.Invoice
           .Where(i => DbFunctions.IsJson(i.InvoiceState) == true)
           .ToLinqToDB().ToList();
```